# R: Keep column names when writing empty dataframe to excel using WriteXLS

Tags: r, excel

I am using the package WriteXLS to write a list in R to excel, with each element of a list going on a seperate sheet.

This works fine unless any of the dataframes are empty - for empty dataframes it writes the column names as 'X.WRITEXLS.COMMENT' whereas I want the actual column names to be displayed.

For example lets create a test list and write to excel

```
library(WriteXLS)
testList <- list('mysheet1' = data.frame('a' = numeric(), 'b' = numeric(), 'c' = numeric()), 'mysheet2' = data.frame('a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3))
WriteXLS("testList", ExcelFileName = 'test.xlsx')
```

The second element of the list is fine, but for the first element is column names in excel are 'X.WRITEXLS.COMMENT', whereas I want them to be a, b and c as they are in the list in R.

The function works as I would expect (printing correct column names) in an old version of WriteXLS (2.1.1) but doesn't work for me in the current version (3.5.0)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the maintainer of the package Marc Schwartz aware of this, and he has fixed this in the latest version of the package 3.5.1